# org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["ListeCar"] not found

Tags: java, json, netbeans

I want to read this JSON file with java using json library

```
"ListeCar": [
    {
        "id": "R",
        "size": "2",
        "Orientation": "Horizontal",
        "Position": {
            "Row": "2",
            "Column": "0"
        }
    }
```

This is my java code :

```
package rushhour;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.json.*;


public class JsonClass {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {


    try{
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Nuno\\Desktop\\School\\clg-g41326\\RushHourJson.json"));

        JSONObject jsonObject =  (JSONObject) obj;

        JSONArray Liste = obj.getJSONArray("ListeCar");
        String listeCar = Liste.getJSONObject(0).getString("id");
        for (int i = 0; i <Liste.length(); i++) {
        String id = Liste.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
        System.out.println(id);
        String size = Liste.getJSONObject(i).getString("size");
        System.out.println(size);
        String Orientation = Liste.getJSONObject(i).getString("Orientation");
        System.out.println(Orientation);
        String Position = Liste.getJSONObject(i).getString("Position");
        System.out.println(Position);    
        }
    }catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
}
}
```

I'm doing this in netbeans and it's kind a my first time using Json !
I want just to do a system.out from this little json code. I don't know why he's not finding the file that i put in the new JSONObjet ...

Comment: you are not using a valid json. Please correct the format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{
      "ListeCar":[
       {
           "id":"R",
           "size":"2",
           "Orientation":"Horizontal",
           "Position":{
                "Row":"2",
                "Column":"0"
            }
      }]
}
```

try placing this in your .json file
your json is not valid... try placing it in this site to check for it's validity.... http://json.parser.online.fr/

And the code for the correct output....

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException, ParseException {
    try {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("/home/Desktop/temp.json"));
        JSONObject objJsonObject = new JSONObject(obj.toString());
        System.out.println(objJsonObject);
        JSONArray Liste = objJsonObject.getJSONArray("ListeCar");
        String listeCar = Liste.getJSONObject(0).getString("id");
        for (int i = 0; i < Liste.length(); i++) {
            String id = Liste.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
            System.out.println(id);
            String size = Liste.getJSONObject(i).getString("size");
            System.out.println(size);
            String Orientation = Liste.getJSONObject(i).getString("Orientation");
            System.out.println(Orientation);
            String Position = Liste.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("Position").toString();
            System.out.println(Position);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You forgot to parse json... which is done in the above code.... a link about the tutorial on how to do this is as follows:: http://crunchify.com/how-to-read-json-object-from-file-in-java/

Comment: Unfortunately it gives me the same problem :/

Comment: have your checked for the validity of your json file using the link above?

Comment: Exactly , my json is not valid .. my listCar i think

Comment: @NunoDores - hope the above is what you wanted... if yes don't forget to mark this answer as the right one... it might help others in the future..

Comment: happy to solve your problem... don't forget to upvote and mark this as the correct answer :)