# JSONObject.toString("variable") claims field is not there even when copy pasted from browser api call

Tags: java, json, rest

I'm trying to make a program that makes use of an MLB information API located [here](https://appac.github.io/mlb-data-api-docs/#player-data-player-search-get). I can retrieve all of the information about a player, but can't seem to get the toString() method to pull more specific information from the json response.

Response:

```
{"search_player_all":{"copyRight":" Copyright 2019 MLB Advanced Media, L.P.  Use of any content on this page acknowledges agreement to the terms posted here http://gdx.mlb.com/components/copyright.txt  ","queryResults":{"totalSize":"1","created":"2019-05-28T12:34:47","row":{"college":"","pro_debut_date":"2012-09-05T00:00:00","birth_city":"Amsterdam","name_display_first_last":"Didi Gregorius","birth_date":"1990-02-18T00:00:00","height_inches":"3","team_id":"147","birth_state":"","name_last":"Gregorius","active_sw":"Y","birth_country":"Netherlands","bats":"L","player_id":"544369","service_years":"","name_display_last_first":"Gregorius, Didi","name_first":"Didi","league":"AL","weight":"205","name_use":"Didi","sport_code":"mlb","throws":"R","high_school":"","team_code":"nya","team_full":"New York Yankees","team_abbrev":"NYY","height_feet":"6","position":"SS","name_display_roster":"Gregorius","position_id":"6"}}}}
```

My code to process json:

```
JSONObject responsejson = response.getBody().getObject();
String test = responsejson.getString("copyRight");
```

Note: I am using org.json.JSONObject to process.

I would hope that it would return:

```
Copyright 2019 MLB Advanced Media, L.P.  Use of any content on this 
page acknowledges agreement to the terms posted here 
http://gdx.mlb.com/components/copyright.txt
```

but instead I just get:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["copyRight"] not found.
```

Any help appreciated.

Edit: As others have noted, copyRight isn't a top level entry, however, when I try getString("search_player_all") I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["search_player_all"] not a string.
```

Solution: I used .getJSONObject() to navigate down to the row level. Thank you for the help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.json.JSONException: JSONObject\["ListeCar"\] not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36766918/org-json-jsonexception-jsonobjectlistecar-not-found)

Comment: You are trying to get `copyRight` from `responsejson`, which has only one object inside called `search_player_all`: as you can see the object you are searching for is *inside* that one, so you need to get `search_player_all` first and then get `copyRight` from it.

Comment: @Smutje - I don't see how. That question asks about parsing JSON which is malformed. The above isn't malformed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your top-level object doesn't have a `copyRight` property, it has a `search_player_all` property whose value is an object with a `copyRight` property. You need to get that first:

```
JSONObject responsejson = response.getBody().getObject();
JSONObject search_player_all = responsejson.getJSONObject("search_player_all"); // Or maybe .getObject("search_player_all") with the lib you're using...?
String test = search_player_all.getString("copyRight");
```